# Value on Input didnt change when state change on React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

can you please help me with this?
I need to have a input that read his value from the property "cantidad" on the redux state, so, when the "cantidad" property changes the input value changes too, im achieving changing the "cantidad" on the redux state, but no on the component itself.
This should be simple but i cant get id done.

My state:

```
carrito: {
    articulosEnCarrito: [
      {
        id: '3937',
        cantidad: 15
      }
    ],
    total: 0
  },
```

My component:

```
const ControlDeCantidades = props => {

const handleAumentarCantidad = id => {
   props.agregarACarrito(id);
};

const articulo = props.articulosEnCarrito.find(
  articulo => articulo.id === props.idDeArticulo
);

return (
<div>
   <button type="button" onClick={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleReducirCantidad(props.idDeArticulo);
   }}
   >
   <input type="number" defaultValue={articulo.cantidad} />
</div>
 );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    articulosEnCarrito: state.carrito.articulosEnCarrito
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ControlDeCantidades);
```

i expect the value of the input to change when the 'cantidad' value on the redux state changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example of a full [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

```
const Input = () =>{
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    return(
        <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    )
}
```

Just passing value to an input without a way to update it makes the input controlled and uncontrolled, you should provide a callback to update the value to. Using classes:

```
class Input extends React.Component{
    state ={ value: ''}
    onChangeHandler = e => this.setState({value: e.target.value})

    render(){
        return(
            <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me,
i dont need a input, a simple text its ok, i only need that the text show the value of the property "cantidad" from the redux state when the property chenges...

i try with...
       `{
          props.articulosEnCarrito.find(
            articulo => articulo.id === props.idDeArticulo
          ).cantidad
        }`

but, no luck for me, this shuold be a really simple solution.

Comment: i solved it, it was a problem with the reducers, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look at your reducer. I'm also not sure if you are using it yet, but you haven't defined mapDispatchToProps()

Comment: Thank for supporting the community! :D Just a tip: When you have just a comment, don't post it as an answer, or provide a more complete description so it can be considered an actual answer